# Using Bitcoin Core on Ubuntu. How to claim BCH & BTG while keeping whole BTC blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoin-cash, wallet.dat, bitcoin-gold

I'm using the Bitcoin Core client on Ubuntu.  I've got the whole ~170GB blockchain on my hard drive.  I'd like to be able to claim my BCH and BTG while preserving that blockchain, though if I don't have to keep multiple copies of the chain from before the forks, that would be optimal.  Does anyone have a suggestion of what wallet(s) and procedures to use?  Note that since the splits, I have had a single transaction out of the wallet which is, unfortunately, sitting in limbo.

Comment: @Adam - that doesn't appear to be a duplicate because (1) it doesn't discuss BTG, and most importantly (2) it appears to necessitate my having two copies of the whole chain.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Are you planning on keeping the forked coins locally too? In that case you'll need the forked blockchains. I guess theoretically you could share the common pre-fork data between chains, but it looks tricky and if a client changes their blockchain database structure in the future it'll break.

Comment: @Adam.  I see.  Ok, yes, the plan is to keep them all locally.  So in this case, I will just have to get an extra hard drive or two for this.  I'm reading on claiming BCH now, so it looks like I'm left with my question (1), claiming BTG.  Also, I'm vague on whether this post-fork limbo transaction will create any obstacles.

Comment: The process is no different for BTG. Use a Bitcoin Gold client, import your wallet or keys. Backup your Bitcoin wallet first to make sure it doesn't get overwritten by software or user error in the process.

Comment: [try this](https://www.bitcoin.com/guides/how-to-access-your-bitcoin-cash-bcc-bch)

Comment: @Adam - So I've been poking around with bitcoinabc on ubuntu.  What I see is that if I install it, it writes over the bitcoind and bitcoin-qt binaries of the Bitcoin Core, replacing them with its own.  So there's no way to run these side by side, even if I keep two copies of the blockchain.